# Load Image based on what the user typed on a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have a working script here about loading an existing image on my local storage.

**How it works:**
At first the div has a default image to represent  that an image will be loaded there so
 if the name is typed it will then display the image on that div if that name exist

**The Problem is:**
It does load the correct image but when a user is typing the div section it becomes like this

[image: Screenshot]

but after the user is done typing it loads the image correctly

Here is my code:

JS

```
//setup before functions
var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
var doneTypingInterval = 5000;  //time in ms, 5 second for example

//on keyup, start the countdown
$('#email').keyup(function(){

    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    var email = $('#email').val();
    $('#ico-pro').html('<img src="temp/users/'+email+'.jpg">');
    typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);

});

//on keydown, clear the countdown 
$('#email').keydown(function(){
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);

});

//user is "finished typing," do something
function doneTyping () {
  var email = $('#email').val();
    $('#ico-pro').html('<img src="temp/users/'+email+'.jpg">');
}
```

my HTML file

```
  <figure class="uk-thumbnail">
        <div id="ico-pro" class="ico-profile"><img src='temp/users/user-pic.jpg' width=75 height=75 /></div>
      </figure>
      <fieldset class="email">
      <input type='text' id='email' value="">
      </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you put it on a demo, so we can play at it

it seems to me your current logic is

```
keydown    -> clearTimer
keyUp      -> clearTimer(again, in case key isnt released)
              >>>>> you've change the dom here as well... <<<<
              setTimer
idle(5000) -> execute done(change dom)
```

1 - in your keyup function, between clearTimer and setTimer, you've already started to grab the unfinished value from the input and append to img.src

2 - i would say remove the clearTimer at the keyUp, its duplicated

3 - you need a to clear your typingTimer variable in done()

4 - you should put up a dummy or loading image, and use ajax to load the image, if it fails... we show the dummy, if it return image, show the image, that way you dont need to worry about the timer, unless you don't want loads of ajax calls.